# How to call async-wait method in any function by using callback

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

I am using [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) in **Unity 2020.3**.
And I want to call an async method which returns a UniTask in Unity Event Function.

For some reason, I cannot change the event function to async version, is there any other way to call it?

Such as, wrap the async method into a callback function?

---

For example, I have an async function like this:

```
public void async UniTask<string> GetStringAsync();
```

And I want to call it like below:

```
public class MyMonoBehaviour: MonoBehaviour
{
   pirvate string myString;


   pirvate void Start()
   {
       myString = await GetStringAsync();
   }
}
```

I cannot use await in `Start()` because it is not an async function.
So, I want to wrap `GetStringAsync()` into a callback function and call it in `Start()`, but I have no idea how to do it.

I know the simplest solution is to change `Start()` to `async Start()`,

But what if I want to call `GetStringAsync()` in any normal function? Change it to async again?
I dislike the `async` spread in my code like virus. Because the function may be some legacy code, I want to modify it as little as possible.

Comment: Could you show your code and explain a bit further what exactly you are trying to do and what you tried?

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for you reply, I have update the question and add more detail.

Comment: `I  cannot use await in Start() because it is not an async function` .. well have you tried making it `async`? ^^

Comment: @derHugo Yes, making it async is the simplest solution, I just wonder is it possible to wrap an async function to callback.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by that but yes Unity allows to make `Start` an async method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I wanted for myself.

I create two wrapper function like below:

```
public void GetString(Action<string> onDone) {
    AsyncToCallbackAsync(onDone).Forget();
}

private async UniTask AsyncToCallbackAsync(Action<string> onDone) {
    string s = await GetStringAsync();
    onDone(s);
}
```

And I can call `GetString()` in any normal function by using callback.
Maybe I didn't describe my question clearly, but this is the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by changing the signature to `async void Start()`. That works. If you need `Update` to be delayed until `Start` finishes, change `Start` to a coroutine and use UniTask's API for creating an iterator from a task (which you will yield).

Note: I don't use the `UniTask` library, but it seems pretty equivalent to `Async Await Utils`. Both provide the `GetAwaiter()` extension method for common Unity types. There is certainly some function that lets a coroutine wait for a task (by wrapping it in an `IEnumerator`).

Comment: Hi @piojo , if I cannot change Start() to async version, is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Yongyi I haven't found any situation where I couldn't change the `Start()` signature to `async`, even when using inheritance or interfaces. But if you can't, you can accomplish this by making an `async void` helper method and calling that from `Start()`. `async void StartAsync() { await GetStringAsync(); } void Start() { StartAsync(); }`

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this article](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/) "Methods that are marked as `async void` represent the root level ‘entry point’ for some async behaviour. A good way to think about them is that they are ‘fire and forget’ tasks that go off and execute some number of things in the background while any calling code immediately continues on."
So, you can create your own "root" *async void* method and call it directly from **void Start**. For example:

```
void Start()
{
    Load();
}

async void Load()
{
    myString = await GetStringAsync();
}
```